# catch is not working and doesn't return error message

Tags: .net-core, error-handling, try-catch

code to for exception handling

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Error while downloading package");
        }
```

Comment: What's in the `try` part?

Comment: What do you mean by "return error message"? What exception do you think is occurring here? We need to see more code.